# Search on Documentation only

Tags: feature-request, documentation, search

I'd like to be able to do text searches on Documentation only using the "Search Q&A" bar on top, which would probably need to change its name to "Search Documentation" when you're there.

Comment: The "search Q&A" bar on top still only searches within the Q&A. I don't even know if there is a search capability for Documentation except searching for tags...